# Simulate Image click from data attribute jquery

Tags: jquery

I am writing a small script to open a bootstrap modal from jquery. This is part of a Android App so if the user has the application installed, the link will deeplink into the app, other wise I want to show a modal.

This is what I currently have.

```
<img class="shareImage" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#shareModal" src="share.png" width="35px"/>
```

This is the function for the alert. This is not working, how can I fix it?

```
function showalert() {
    $('img[data-target="#shareModal"]').click(function(event) {
        console.log("sadsfg");
    });
}
```

My timeout.

```
setTimeout(showalert, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was a lot easier than I was making it to be.

I was able to successfully do this with this line of code.

```
$('.shareImage').click();
```